# Registry redirection does not happen for HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: c#, registry

I have the following code:

```
RegistryKey objRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MySettings\\Dwm\\Preferences", true);
```

I have a registry key present under: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MySettings\Dwm\Preferences` and so this works fine.

When I change the above code to read from local machine instead of current user:

```
RegistryKey objRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MySettings\\Dwm\\Preferences", true);
```

and create the following registry under:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySettings\Dwm\Preferences`

The code returns null. I understand the reason being that due to registry redirection for 32 bit applications on a 64 bit OS, it tries to read the registry from:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\MySettings\Dwm\Preferences`
and since the registry does not exists, it returns null.
The question is that why redirection only happens for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and not for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?

Comment: Registry redirection on HKLM keys is not a basic "always redirect" affair.  Whether they are redirected, reflected or shared follows a set of [quite convoluted rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx).  There are just many less rules for HKCU, mostly because the keys there are for use by non-Microsoft apps and those apps already know what flavor they are.  Only CLSID and AppId values are reflected.  You mis-spelled Wow6432Node btw, letter oh, not digit zero.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Registry Redirection isn't a binary option - either present or not. Sometimes you *want* both 32-bit and 64-bit applications to have the same "view" of (part of) the registry and in other cases you do not.

That's why the specific [keys affected by redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx) are documented. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` itself is shared, as is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`. However, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID`, which includes COM component registration data (which is necessarily 32/64 bit split) does perform redirection.

Or, to put it another way, if registry redirection was universal, you wouldn't need all of this convolution involving `Wow6432Node`, etc. You'd just have a 32-bit registry and a 64-bit registry.